# How to remove arm64 support from Xcode 6?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

Is it possible *not* to support `arm64` using Xcode 6?

> Update with answer (the option is visible when `All` is selected):
>
> [image]

Comment: you can remove that from the build setting, I tried and feels the same as we do in Xcode 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You go to the Navigator Inspector and select your project. Then you select your Target and Build Settings. Search for "Valid Architectures and remove arm64. That will be enough.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue - only want to produce 32 bit.   I solved this with the related setting "Build Active Architecture Only"  Set these to NO, and the problem solved.