# Do I need to do anything special for 64-bit apps written in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to iOS development. I have developed an app entirely in Swift.

I was wondering if apps developed with Swift (Xcode 6.0.1) need any special care to meet the 64-bit requirements?

I am using the default build settings:

```
Standard architectures(armv7, arm64) – $(ARCHS_STANDARD)
```

Is there anything I need to do to make sure it meets 64-bit requirements?

Comment: No you should be good to go. As long as you have your Architectures set to the default Xcode build setting of Standard architectures, which it seems like you do, then you're done.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26796934/1702413

Answer (score 1):

By default 64 bit architecture is preferred (see [How to remove arm64 support from Xcode 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25928938/how-to-remove-arm64-support-from-)). **You have to go out of your way to remove `arm64` (64 bit) support** (in Xcode 6).

In your code, *most commonly* you should use things like `Int` which automatically adjusts to the device's architecture (see [this](http://sketchytech.blogspot.com/2014/10/swift-by-numbers-long-and-short-of-it.html) for more detail) to ensure support, instead of `Int32` or the 64 bit variant; However this is only for performance reasons (which is still important!).